# How to copy json file to Amazon S3 using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am experimenting with writing a json file to AWS S3. Below is the sample code. This is the file I want to write 'fileNew.json'. And 'fileOld.json' is an existing file in S3, which I included in the code by mistake and shouldnt be in the code.

```
df.to_json('fileNew.json', orient='records',lines=True)

os.system('aws s3 cp fileNew.json s3://sbx-myproject/fileOld.json --sse')
```

Will the above command replace the existing file ? OR will it be just unsuccessful in creating the new file ?

Comment: if you're using Python you should probably be using the boto3 library... just sayin'

Comment: It will replace the existing file. S3 doesn't care about the filename `fileNew.json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a file already exists it will be automatically overwritten. So yes `fileOld.json` will be replaced with the file you are uploading.

While your code will work, it is recommended you use the AWS SDK instead of executing shell commands.

```
import boto3

data = open('fileNew.json', 'rb')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('sbx-myproject').put_object(Key='fileOld.json', Body=data)
```